# String was not recognized as a valid date time with DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, datetime

Here is the string I'm passing into `DateTime.ParseExact`

```
var dateTime = "2015-04-07 0‎6‎:‎00‎:‎00‎ ‎AM";
```

here is the code

```
DateTime dateWithTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I'm getting a format exception that says

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Answer (score 2):

You have invisible symbols in your `dateTime` string (left-to-right marks), you can see them if you look into HTML of this page. I don't sure if they are originally from your code, or added somehow when posted on SO, but when I copy it directly to Visual Studio, the same error occurs. When I re-type manually, it works.

Copy and paste it into your code:

```
var dateTime = "2015-04-07 06:00:00 AM";
```

Comment: so how do I check for these and how do I get rid of them?

Comment: @user1186050 I updated the answer. Just replace this line in your code by copy and paste.

Comment: @user1186050 you may want to remove everything that is not alphanumeric or space for example (i.e with regex like `[^a-z0-9 ]`).

Comment: but I would want to keep dashes '-' and colons ':' so how would I keep these?

Comment: @user1186050 `var dateTime = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("2015-04-07 0‎6‎:‎00‎:‎00‎ ‎AM", @"[^a-z0-9-:\s]", "");` will remove all unnecessary symbols but leave dashes and colons.

Comment: this removes the 'AM' and 'PM' from the string.

Comment: I tried this and included ^A-Za-z0-9-:\s but it doesn't pull all the invisible characters out.

Comment: @user1186050 try this: `var dateTime = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("2015-04-07 0‎6‎:‎00‎:‎00‎ ‎AM", @"[^A-Za-z0-9-: ]", "");`.